# get name of current SmartVariant

Tags: sapui5

What is the name of the currently selected Variant in a smartFilterBar?

In the event 'afterVariantLoad' of the smartFilterBar the ID of the selected Variant can be retrieved with: `oEvent.getSource().getSmartVariant().lastSelectedVariantKey`. But the ID is generated and not useful for the actual usecase.

How to get the Name and content of the variant from there?

UseCase:
On a specific Variant a DateRangePicker should always select a range of 13 Months starting with January of July, whatever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the available variants

```
oEvent.getSource().getSmartVariant().getVariantItems();
```

and find the variant content by filtering the key.

```
oEvent.getSource().getSmartVariant().getSelectionKey();
```